# make error when trying install TP link USB wifi drivers

Tags: server, usb, 22.04, make

I tried installing a driver for my TP-Link wifi adapter but I ran into some error(s)

OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-91-generic

commands ran:

```
cd wifi adapter driver folder
```

```
    sudo make
    
    error:
    make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-91-generic/build M=/home/coen/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047  modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-91-generic'
    scripts/Makefile.lib:10: *** Recursive variable 'KBUILD_CFLAGS' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:1909: /home/coen/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-91-generic'
    make: *** [Makefile:1828: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you trying the official from Realtek? I would suggest building one that is actually maintained, such as [this one](https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux).

Comment: Please run and post: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 it displays: Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:0107 TP-Link TL-WN821N v5/v6 [RTL8192EU]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: @vidarloif I chmod744 the install file it gives me an error when i do ./install_wifi.sh: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8192eu': Operation not permitted

Comment: What does this tell us? `modinfo rtl8xxxu | grep 0107`

Comment: @chili555 I ran it and it puts out `alias:          usb:v2357p0107d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*`

Comment: @chili555 @vidarlo I think it all works. Booting does took `long at Load/Save RF kill` and ` a start job is running for wait for network to be configured` but when it finally boots it works I think. (With the drivers from vidarlo) now I just hope that it gets fixed soon (also I had to enroll key from secureboot and I firstly forgot to and when installing the drivers it gave me an error)   Okey edit: it actually killed my whole networking

Comment: Why not use the built-in driver rtl8xxxu then??

Comment: @chili555 using the built-in drivers the wifi adapter does nothing/ not show up

Comment: Above, you said, "I think it all works" Do you need any further assistance?

Comment: @chili555 after reinstalling it works. Now I only have to find out how I add my docker container to the wifi adapter :) so I don't think I need more help. Atleast on this